# How to say to end a topic that I have no idea to say

Tags: conversation

Sometimes when I was talking with people, suddenly I have no idea what to say to move on. At this moment, what can I say to end the topic and restart a new one?

Comment: This has been suggested for closing. I shall vote against that because it seems to me you are merely asking about a list of possible phatic expressions. People interested in language are not usually interested in such questions, and they may be better directed to a site devoted to manners and social intercourse. Nevertheless, it is technically a question about language. Two out of a numerous list are "Excuse me for changing the topic, but..." and "And now for something completely different ...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options one could say -
1. “Well that’s that. Moving on...”
2. “Have you heard that...”
3. “Did you know...”
4. “I got to go. Catch you later.”
5. “It was nice talking to you. See you later.”